# Spring MVC Checkbox Binding Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**Problem**: Checkboxes values are not being bound to my form, properly. The result is that all my boolean values are null (at least the ones not being bound), and the existing ones are not being updated with values changed by the user.

**Details**: I'm aware that checkboxes are not submitted to the server if they are not selected.  However, I do see the values in the request when hooking up an Eclipse debugger.  The data is populated using jQuery/Datatable, but the data is posted back to the server using a form submit.

Spring MVC Version: 3.2.8
I'm assuming its configuration, but I'm not seeing where I am wrong.  Here is a small code snippet of what I'm doing in my controller.

```
@Controller
public class CheckboxController {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "saveCheckboxes*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveCheckboxes(@ModelAttribute(SESSION_FORM_KEY) CheckboxForm form, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

          // VALIDATE HERE...
          if ( !result.hasErrors() ) {
              // SAVE
          }
          else {
              // DON'T SAVE (alert user)
          }
    }
}
```

So Spring MVC is used to binding request inputs to my form.  The form is defined below, which has a list of summary objects with a boolean property.

```
public class CheckboxForm {
    private List<Summary> summaries;
    ...
}

public class Summary {
   private boolean selected;
   ...
}
```

I use jQuery/Datatables to populate my online grid of data.  The inputs are created dynamically using a callback within datatables.

```
var tableWidget = (function($) {

init = function() {
    ...
    "aoColumnDefs": [
         { "aTargets": [0], "sName": "", "mData": "selected" "stype": "html", "sClass": "center", "mRender": renderCheckbox, "bSortable":false, "sWidth": "50px" }
    ...
};

renderCheckbox = function(source, type, row) {
    var $name  = 'checkboxForm.summaries['+row.index+'].selected';
    return createCheckbox($name, source);
};

createCheckbox = function(name, checked) {
    var $checked = (checked === true) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
    return '<input type="checkbox" name="'+name+'" value="true"'+$checked+'/><input type="hidden" name="_'+name+'" value="on"/>';
}
...
))(jQuery);
```

After all of this, I hooked up the debugger and traced it into the WebDataBinder.  I found that it seems to throw and exception in the method:

```
public boolean isWritableProperty(String propertyName)
```

saying the property cannot be evaluated.  This happens for each property returned.  However, I can confirm that what is in the request is the very inputs that I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

First, unless you know why avoid relative URL in `@RequestMapping` methods. It is a common cause of errors.

Next, as you directly generate your checkboxes without all the bells and whistles that adds `spring:checkbox`, you wont't get automatic error messages, and could experience problems in getting last checkboxes values if they are unchecked, as they will not be transmitted by browser and Spring will never see them giving a shorter list (or even an empty list if all are unchecked).

That being said, your problem is that you use `checkboxForm.summaries[index].selected` where Spring would expect only `summaries[index].selected`. Remove `checkboxForm`and your controller should affect values to the `@ModelAttribute CheckboxForm form`.